# Search multiply files in folder by name and copy them to other forlder

Tags: file, search

I have more than 300 file names.
I need to find that files by name and move to other location

I have try to search with OR between file names but from all list only 7 files come up

Any ideas how to do it fast?

I can't find any macro command with this

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil,os
for i in os.listdir(dirname):
    if filenamelist.__contains__(i):
        shutil.copy(dirname+'/'+i,locationtocopyto)
```

is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found this
and It's working

```
 Sub copyfiles()
'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    Dim xSFileDlg As FileDialog, xDFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xSPathStr As Variant, xDPathStr As Variant
    Dim xVal As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", "KuTools For Excel", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xSFileDlg.Title = "Please select the original folder:"
    If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xDFileDlg.Title = "Please select the destination folder:"
    If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    For Each xCell In xRg
        xVal = xCell.Value
        If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
            FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```